# n/2 bit multiplication on an n bit cpu

Tags: algorithm, cpu, bit

I was looking at an algorithm which multiplied 2 n bit numbers with 3 multiplications of n/2 bits. This algorithm is considered efficient. While I understand that space is obviously conserved, if I were working on an n bit machine , how would n/2 bit multiplications be better. Those n/2 bit multiplications would be converted to n bit multiplications because the CPU can only understand n bit numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is pure speculation, but sounds like this is not a software technique then but a hardware thing, i.e. you have a 16-bit multiplier block in hardware, and using this algorithm you can use these blocks to build something that looks like a 32-bit multiplier from the outside.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the algorithm and exactly what is meant by "efficient"? And I suppose there are some conditions associated with it.

Comment: check Gauss multiplication. It is usually done for complex number but the theory can be applied to any 2 n bit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms like [Karatsuba multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or [Toom-Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) are typically used in the implementation of "bignums" -- computation with numbers of unlimited size. Generally speaking, the more sophisticated the algorithm, the larger numbers need to be to make it worthwhile doing.

There are a variety of bignum packages; one of the more commonly used ones is the Gnu Multiprecision library, [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/), which includes a large number of different multiplication algorithms, selecting the appropriate one based on the length of the multiplicands. (According to wikipedia, the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm), which is based on the fast Fourier transform algorithm, isn't used until the multiplicands reach 33,000 decimal digits. Such computations are relatively rare, but when you have to do such a computation, you probably care about it being done efficiently.)

Comment: well that does not quite answer my question. I am saying how does a n-bit computer handle n/2 bit computations ? If it handles it the same was as n bit computations then there is no need to try implement Gauss .

Comment: @user590849: What is your mental model of an n-bit computer? Might a computer have, for example, a 64-bit ALU and 4 32-bit ALUs? Or, is 64-bit multiplication performed directly in silicon, or is it microcoded using simpler components? And what would "directly in silicon" mean, anyway... certainly it doesn't mean a 128-bit-indexed lookup table :) But perhaps that's not what you're asking either.

Comment: ... On the whole, if a machine has an opcode to do multiplication of some size, I'd be inclined to let it do that, even if it involved some complex and inefficient microcode, on the grounds that the next generation of the same CPU will probably do it better. On the other hand, if the n-bit multiplication is being done by a software library included in the compiler, I might, under some circumstances, have a whack at improving it.